# Why do Safari and Firefox seem to incorrectly render my gradient and how can I fix it?

Tags: css, linear-gradients, gradient

[Here's the code on CodePen](http://codepen.io/curtisblackwell/pen/djGrq). It looks exactly as I expect in Chrome. Firefox and Safari both look wrong. (I'm on the latest versions of all 3.)

I'm working on a way to use a constant gradient background across multiple `inline-block` elements. Here's how it's working right now:

1. I have a parent `ol` whose `:before` pseudo-element has a gradient background (`transparent` to opaque color) and a `z-index` set to display it above the child `li`s.
2. The `li`s have the `background-color` set to the color that *looks like* what the gradient's `transparent` value is set to.
3. The `li`'s `color` is set to `transparent` and have `:before` pseudo-elements that display the text that's previously set to `transparent` and have their z-indices set to display above the `ol:before` (with background gradient).

#### The problems I'm seeing in Firefox:

1. The gradient looks like it's got 3 color stops (transparent, grey, transparent) instead of the 2 that are set.
2. The gradient seems as though it's got a multiply blend mode set.

#### The problems I'm seeing in Safari:

In addition to the same problems in Firefox, it also displays two gradients which seem to have multiply blend modes. One from `-webkit-linear-gradient` and one from `linear-gradient`. Solving the issue of the apparent blend mode should take care of this third issue, though.

---

My googling made me aware of `background-blend-mode`, but setting that to `normal` (or any other valid value) changed nothing. I think it only works with multiple backgrounds on a single element, but I'm not sure about that. However, that would explain why it doesn't solve my problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was that I used the keyword `transparent` rather than a transparent version of the color that it was gradating to. The browsers that didn't render the gradient as expected were treating `transparent` as transparent black. That meant that different gradations between black and my color were present in the gradient.

I'm using SASS so the fix is pretty simple: Just use the `rgba()` function to convert my hex color to rgba.

`background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, rgba($brand-primary, 0), $brand-primary);`

I updated [the code on CodePen](http://codepen.io/curtisblackwell/pen/djGrq) to show the solution.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this prefix for some browsers which don't take the styles

for mozilla use

```
-moz-linear-gradient   /* FF3.6+ */
```

for chrome/safari

```
-webkit-gradient     /* Chrome,Safari4+ */

-webkit-linear-gradient   /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
```

for opera

```
 -o-linear-gradient    /* Opera 11.10+ */
```

for ie 10 +

```
-ms-linear-gradient  /* IE10+ */
```

i have edited you codepen by adding prefix check it [**JS Fiddle**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hpdxu)

Comment: The necessary prefixes are already there. CodePen is using auto-prefixer. Also, gradients no longer need any prefixes for any current versions, see [Can I use…](http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient).