# Safari doesn't render css gradient text

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm trying to make gradient text in webkit browsers using this CSS code:

```css
.text {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(blue, green);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

it works perfectly in Chrome, but in Safari (both 8 and 9) it doesn't render gradient text unless you select it via mouse click+drag over it.

HTML is as follows:

```
<p class = "text">Hello world.</p>
```

Spent 2 evening on that. Found a lot of recommendations to use this method with couple issues similar to mine and no solutions at all. Would appreciate a lot if someone would help.

IMPORTANT UPDATE:

I've found out, that this code works great when applied to single `<p>` element, but fails to render in Safari (not in chrome) when applied to div wrapper to single or multiple `<p>` elements like this:

```
<div class = "text">    
   <p>First line.</p>
   <p>Second, way longeeeeeeer line. </p>
   <p>Third line, just to see gradient span over multiple lines. </p>
</div>
```

Any thoughts why this could be the case or how to overcome this?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Why do Safari and Firefox seem to incorrectly render my gradient and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291684/why-do-safari-and-firefox-seem-to-incorrectly-render-my-gradient-and-how-can-i-f)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not.

Comment: Ok. I'll test it out on my iPad. Back to you later today (if somebody else doesn't give you a good answer).

Comment: Thank you so much. Please, note that I have added important update.

Comment: So you're saying the gradient works when applied directly to the `<p>` element, but it doesn't cascade when applied to the `<div>` container?

Comment: That's exactly it. And it cascades down in Chrome or Opera, but not in Safari.

Comment: Have you considered just applying the `.text` class to the `<p>` tags?

Comment: It would then render same gradient to each single paragraph, not to the whole text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87428/discussion-between-michael-b-and-o3inc).

Comment: Yeah, I can see the difficulty you're having. There's absolutely nothing online about gradients failing to cascade onto child elements in Safari. At least nothing I have found (and I've looked!).

Comment: I have a couple of workaround ideas. Is this gradient effect something you want to reuse in many places, or just one place?

Answer (score 16):

I found a simple fix for this

```
.text, span {
 display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I know it's an old question but in case someone still needs it: I had the same problem and what worked for me was to add a text-shadow to it and make the shadow transparent.

```
.text {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(blue, green);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
text-shadow: 0px 0px #00000000; <--
}
```

Note that I added '00' to the end of the HEXA code which leads to transparency if someone doesn't know!

Comment: That actually worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Small note: `#00000000` is equivalent to `transparent`.

Answer (score 4):

If you code like this `<h1>Discover <span>Something</span></h1>` then text gradient won't appear in Safari but does appear fine in Chrome and Firefox.

If you do like this `<h1>Discover Something</h1>` without `span` tag then it does work properly. I don't think Safari liked tags inside the tag. Nasty bug. It works on other browsers like Chrome and Safari.

Comment: I reported to webkit bug report. Hopefully they'll resolve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a two lines text and in Safari does not works, try:

```css
-webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
```

Comment: This is the solution that works! It's nice. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3):

`flex` or `inline-flex` are the problems if you are using it.

`block` or `inline-block` are fixing the problem

Comment: It works for me

Answer (score 2):

This remains a Safari bug as of May 2018. The gradient properly appears if the text is first highlighted, and then unhighlighted.

I was able to use the following alternative:

```
.text {
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(blue, green);
}
```

This is working in Safari 11, iOS Safari 11, Chrome 66, and Firefox 60.

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/45136579/9772439

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with `b` tag, and solve it with property

```
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it looks like it's a Safari bug.
I noticed that the issue only happens when your cascading elements are block types.

My hack for this went like this

```
    <div class = "text">    
        <span>First line.</span>
        <p></p>
        <span>Second, way longeeeeeeer line. </span>
        <p></p>
        <span>Third line, just to see gradient span over multiple lines.</span>
        <p></p>
    </div>
```

The only reason I have the paragraph tags is for spacing since adding a display block on the spans will trigger the bug again.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the easiest way to archive this is drawing text as image, contain shadow... And put it in background css.

Comment: Image as vectorised .svg ? If only as .png or .jpg then it won't be so sharp as text around it.

Comment: svg for sure, I've never thought about jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried all of the above and none are working, check to see if you have a Pseudo element on the tag.

Safari doesn't like it if these are static so you'll need to position them absolute.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, for fix it use attribute display with the property "inline" or "inline-block" to the main element, in your case p.text