# Gradient text is not working in safari browser.It is showing white color instead of gradient text

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Below is the code.Gradient not working in safari after using webkits also.

```css
.gradientText{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#862AA5, #CE3E81);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#862AA5, #CE3E81);
  background: -webkit-gradient(#862AA5, #CE3E81);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#862AA5, #CE3E81);
  background:  -ms-linear-gradient(#862AA5, #CE3E81);
  background: linear-gradient(#862AA5, #CE3E81);
  //-webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(#862AA5, #CE3E81);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  //border: 3px solid #fff;
 
}
```

```html
<p class='gradientText'>text
</p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safari doesn't render css gradient text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084460/safari-doesnt-render-css-gradient-text)

Comment: use display:block; instead of flex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084460/safari-doesnt-render-css-gradient-text